# Committed content back in EGit "Unstaged Changes" after branch switch

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, branch, egit

I have committed a changed file in EGit to a branch `buha_faktura_simba` and pushed it to the server. Then I used the Git command console `git checkout master` to checkout the `master` branch. Then I tried to merge `git merge buha_faktura_simba` the `buha_faktura_simba` branch into my `master`, but I get the following error.:

```
$ git merge buha_faktura_simba
Updating f6ea506..21e57c4
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        br_boss_fleet_fleetAccounts/forms/br_boss_fleet_fleetAccounts_dtl.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I had no staged or unstaged changes before branch switch. I looked at the differences `git diff` and that showed me exactly the changes that I have committed before I switched to branch `master`. Then I switched again to branch `buha_faktura_simba` to check `git log` if I really committed my changes before and I see the commit is in the log.

[image: GitLab log double commit]

Why I have this behavior? Maybe I have some Git understanding problems or could this be a bug in EGit/Eclipse/Servoy?

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually commit the changes in the first step. How did you do that, using the staging view or the commit dialog?

Comment: I used the EGit staging view to commit in the first step. What "commit dialog" do you mean?

Comment: I switched again to branch `buha_faktura_simba` to check `git log` if I really committed my changes before and I see the commit is in the log.

Comment: Did you by any chance rename the above file, changing the case (upper case to lower case or vice versa)?